# How to fight beard loss without cortisol injections?

Tags: hair, hairloss, injections, facial-hair

I guess losing beard area as a little blocks is a really bad situation. I asked this issue to a dermatology doctor, she said "Run away from stress". Running away from stress is definitely **impossible** today's world.

The doctor said: "I can inject cortisol liquid into the skin". Maybe acceptable, but however the lose may keep going, though. After injections, the skin is going down and begin to lose its elasticity, and got old. So, cortisol is harmful for skin even though it was a bit good choice. (Cortisol has made some weight on a skin and body)

Trying garlics with salt on a skin is offered among people near you, but the skin got red, and burned, and didn't fix.

**How can we stop the loss of beard?**

Edit: (01.02.2015) A different doctor said: "This is Alopecia Areata. If cortisol didn't care, Tacrolimus Monohidrat Pomad Creams may be a good choice to care", and  "The skin is begun to get repaired itself within 2 months if the cream is used twice a day"

Comment: If you want a constructive answer, you may want to specify _why_ you are experiencing hair loss. Hair on your face tends to stay there in the absense of a medical condition. If your doctor hasn't provided you with a diagnosis, you may want to ask for one, or even get a second opinion. Most forms of hair loss are at least somewhat treatable, if you know what's causing them.

Comment: At the moment, this is clearly written as a personal medical question.  If you would like to try and re-write the question so that it is a general question (not tied to you personally), we can keep it open and give it a chance to be answered.

Comment: @Bay What exactly does "neighbor beard areas are already gone after doctor's injection" mean? Did the smooth patches grow back or not? Also, what does "one got some fat" mean? You saw weight gain? This question is a bit unclear about what you're asking and sounds suspiciously like it's asking for a diagnosis, but I've tried to be understanding and edited the question to what I think you're trying to ask. If that's not it, then please feel free to change it back, however please understand that we can't help if we don't understand or you ask for something too general.

Comment: http://www.webmd.com/men/guide/testosterone-replacement-therapy-is-it-right-for-you

Comment: @DaveL I mean with "neighbor area..." is the place on my beard where the near is the harmed area without any harm. "One got..." means that cortisol make you get weight increase.

     CountIblis thanks. I am going to get measured my hormons. That's may be a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the possible treatments for alopecia areata:

- First-line therapies

  - Intralesional corticosteroids
  - Topical corticosteroids
  - Minoxidil Anthralin
  - Topical immunotherapy
  - Prostaglandin analogs
  - Topical retinoids
  - Bexarotene Capsaicin
- Second-line therapies (if first-line ones are not effective)

  - Sulfasalazine
  - Photochemotherapy
  - Excimer laser
  - Fractional photothermolysis laser
- Third-line therapies (if second-line ones are not effective)

  - Systemic corticosteroids
  - Methotrexate
  - Cyclosporine
  - Azathioprine
  - Biologics

The detailed information you can get in ["Alopecia areata: a new treatment plan" by Adel Alsantali in *Clinical, Cosmetic & Investigative Dermatology*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3149478/).